# Java, DynamoDB: Is it possible to custom-marsall a Set?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to annotate a class that has a `Set<UUID>` property. Marshalling a scalar `UUID` is fine, and I can use the `@DynamoDBMarshalling` annotation to specify my converter, and everything works.

When trying to use the same converter on a `Set<UUID>`, I get "DynamoDBMappingException: Expected SS in value". I've tried creating a custom converter that expects `Set<UUID>`, but the same problem persists.

Is it possible to custom-marshall Sets?

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="djones-test")
public class UUIDRecommendation {
    private UUID id;
    private Set<UUID> recommendations;

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass=UuidConverter.class)
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //Neither this nor UuidConverter.class work here    
    @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass=SetUuidConverter.class)
    public Set<UUID> getRecommendations() {
        return recommendations;
    }

    public void setRecommendations(Set<UUID> recommendations) {
        this.recommendations = recommendations;
    }
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Expected SS in value {SS: [1a841b97-ab9d-4425-a2c0-f9a81bebf0b4, 1a841b97-ab9d-4425-a2c0-f9a81bebf0b4, 1a841b97-ab9d-4425-a2c0-f9a81bebf0b4], } when invoking public void com.company.model.UUIDRecommendation.setRecommendations(java.util.Set)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.SUnmarshaller.typeCheck(SUnmarshaller.java:26)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.setValue(DynamoDBMapper.java:329)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObject(DynamoDBMapper.java:302)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:253)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:196)
    at com.mendeley.service.data.DynamoRecommendedItemsDataServiceTest.testObjectMapper(DynamoRecommendedItemsDataServiceTest.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear - looks like customer marshallers of sets is *unpossible*. The AWS SDK is hardcoded to only deal with single string values (SUnmarshaller()).

DynamoDBReflector in AWS SDK 1.3.13, line 185:

```
if ( isCustomMarshaller(getter) ) {
    unmarshaller = new SUnmarshaller() {

        @Override
        public Object unmarshall(AttributeValue value) {
            return getCustomMarshalledValue(toReturn, getter, value);
        }
    };
}
```

**UPDATE**

As an utterly filthy hack, I've cobbled something together that works by copy/pasting the entire class :( This is why private static final utility services are *bad*, and dependency injection is *good*.

This will work so you can use one customer converter (`UuidConverter` in my case) for getters that return `UUID` instances, *or* `Set<UUID>` instances.

I added a method called getCustomMarshalledValueSet, which iterates over the List returned by value.getSS(), calls the custom marshaller for each, and adds the result to a Set which it returns.

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private <T> T getCustomMarshalledValueSet(T toReturn, Method getter, AttributeValue value) {
    DynamoDBMarshalling annotation = getter.getAnnotation(DynamoDBMarshalling.class);
    Class<? extends DynamoDBMarshaller<? extends Object>> marshallerClass = annotation.marshallerClass();

    DynamoDBMarshaller marshaller;
    try {
        marshaller = marshallerClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new DynamoDBMappingException("Couldn't instantiate marshaller of class " + marshallerClass, e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new DynamoDBMappingException("Couldn't instantiate marshaller of class " + marshallerClass, e);
    }

    Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();

    for (String part : value.getSS()) {
        set.add((T) marshaller.unmarshall(getter.getReturnType(), part));
    }

    return (T) set;
}
```

Additionally getArgumentUnmarshaller was changed to bring the isCollection check before the conditional to decide what type of unmarshaller to use, and changed the custom marshaller block to pick the right sort.

```
            if (isCustomMarshaller(getter)) {
                if (isCollection) {
                    unmarshaller = new SSUnmarshaller() {

                        @Override
                        public Object unmarshall(AttributeValue value) {
                            return getCustomMarshalledValueSet(toReturn, getter, value);
                        }
                    };
                } else {
                    unmarshaller = new SUnmarshaller() {

                        @Override
                        public Object unmarshall(AttributeValue value) {
                            return getCustomMarshalledValue(toReturn, getter, value);
                        }
                    };
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this. It handles the marshall/unmarshall inside the getter/setter. I use a similar technique to store `Set<String>` containing JSON, but access it as a `Set<CustomObject>` in my code. I leave the getter/setter alone and use convenience methods instead.

Here's the modified version:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="djones-test")
public class UUIDRecommendation {
    private String id;
    // custom object representation in JVM
    private Set<UUID> recommendations;

    private static final JsonMarshaller<UUID> UUID_MARSHALLER = new JsonMarshaller<UUID>();

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Set<String> holding JSON in DynamoDB
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="recommendations")
    public Set<String> getRecommendations() {
        if (recommendations != null) {
            Set<String> jsonSet = new HashSet<String>(recommendations.size());
            for (UUID recommendation : recommendations) {
                String json = UUID_MARSHALLER.marshall(recommendation);
                jsonSet.add(json);
            }
            return jsonSet;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void setRecommendations(Set<String> jsonSet) {
        if (jsonSet != null) {
            recommendations = new HashSet<UUID>(jsonSet.size());
            for (String json : jsonSet) {
                UUID recommendation = UUID_MARSHALLER.unmarshall(UUID.class, json);
                recommendations.add(recommendation);
            }
        }
    }

    // convenience methods
    @DynamoDBIgnore
    public UUID convenienceMethod(UUID recommendation) {
        return null;
    }

    // custom object
    public class UUID {

    }
}
```

Comment: This works great! It's a bit strange they haven't included a specific function to do it, but this is a nice workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[See this pull requestd](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/pull/64) I attached a modified version of DynamoDBReflector which handles serialization/deserialization of set of aribtrary objects. I have been using it for a while and it works great.